# How to print something from Entry in another window in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Why it does not print the string values I have entered into the textbox in the newwindow?

```
from tkinter import *

def newwindow():
    newwindow = Tk()
    newwindow.title('Sign Up')
    newwindow.geometry('200x400')

    def sign_done():
        david = a.get()
        javed = b.get()
        lbee = Label(newwindow, text=david).pack()
        baeee = Label(newwindow, text=javed).pack()

    a = StringVar()
    b = StringVar()
    user = Entry(newwindow, textvariable=a).pack()
    pword = Entry(newwindow, textvariable=b).pack()

    done = Button(newwindow, text='done now', command=sign_done).pack()

    newwindow.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.title('Gulmeena')
root.geometry("500x200")
button = Button(root, text='Go', command=newwindow).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Please do not use Classes**

Comment: use `Tk` only to create main window. To create any other window use `TopLevel`. And use only one `mainwindow()`

Comment: `var = Widget(...).pack()` assigns `None` to `var` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None`. You have to do it in two lines. `var = Widget(...)` and `var.pack()`. If you don't need `var` then you can do `Widget(...).pack()`

Comment: @furas: you should add your helpful and correct comments as an answer.

Comment: @furas your comment is really helpful, answer it so that I can accept your answer

Comment: @Sawaid both problems are very popular so question should be rather closed as duplicate.

Comment: @mhawke both problems are very popular so question should be rather closed as duplicate.

Comment: @furas I think this should be rather closed as too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Tk` only to create main window. To create any other window use `Toplevel`. And use only one `mainwindow()`.

`var = Widget(...).pack()` assigns `None` to `var` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None`. You have to do it in two lines.

```
var = Widget(...) 
var.pack().
```

If you don't need var then you can do

```
Widget(...).pack()
```

---

To make code more readable

- I use `import tkinter as tk` to show I use `tk.Button`, not `ttk.Button nor my own class`Button`
- I use name `user_var` and `password_var` which means something
- I put all functions at the beginning - even inside `newwindow`

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def newwindow():

    def sign_done():
        david = user_var.get()
        javed = password_var.get()
        tk.Label(newwindow, text=david).pack()
        tk.Label(newwindow, text=javed).pack()

    newwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow.title('Sign Up')
    newwindow.geometry('200x400')

    user_var = tk.StringVar()
    password_var = tk.StringVar()

    user = tk.Entry(newwindow, textvariable=user_var)
    user.pack()
    pword = tk.Entry(newwindow, textvariable=password_var)
    pword.pack()

    tk.Button(newwindow, text='done now', command=sign_done).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Gulmeena')
root.geometry("500x200")

tk.Button(root, text='Go', command=newwindow).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

You can do the same without `StringVar`s

```
import tkinter as tk

def newwindow():

    def sign_done():
        david = user.get()
        javed = pword.get()
        tk.Label(newwindow, text=david).pack()
        tk.Label(newwindow, text=javed).pack()

    newwindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newwindow.title('Sign Up')
    newwindow.geometry('200x400')

    user = tk.Entry(newwindow)
    user.pack()
    pword = tk.Entry(newwindow)
    pword.pack()

    tk.Button(newwindow, text='done now', command=sign_done).pack()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Gulmeena')
root.geometry("500x200")

tk.Button(root, text='Go', command=newwindow).pack()

root.mainloop()
```